# Is the Azure notification hub available to use?

Tags: azure, azureportal

We are developing a website and would like to use the Azure portal notification module. Does anyone know what this is built with and if we could implement this on our site rather than building from scratch? We have some some processes that take some time so want users to be able to go off and do other things and come back when it's completed.  We host our product on Azure so if this is using an Azure feature then we can use this also.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Azure Notification Hubs provide an easy-to-use and scaled-out push engine that allows you to send notifications to any platform (iOS, Android, Windows, Kindle, Baidu, etc.) from any backend (cloud or on-premises).

Push notifications are delivered through platform-specific infrastructures called Platform Notification Systems (PNSes). They offer barebone push functionalities to deliver a message to a device with a provided handle, and have no common interface. To send a notification to all customers across the Android, iOS, and Windows versions of an app, the developer must work with Apple Push Notification Service(APNS), Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM), and Windows Notification Service(WNS) separately.
Kindly take a look at the documents to know how it works, scenarios you could leverage Azure Notification Hubs for and how to integrate with your app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-overview

https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-app-service

Do provide more details on your requirement for better assistance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ajay, I have added a picture to my original question to better describe what I'm referring to in the portal. So do you know if this feature in the portal is built using the notification hubs that you talk about above?

Answer (score 0):

The question is tagged for Azure Notification Hubs, but the screen shot you showing is for the notification section of the Azure Portal UI. I'm not aware that Microsoft makes the component available for third-party use.

Can you please remove the Notification Hubs tag from this issue as it's not related.